# remove older posts link

Tags: posts, navigation

I use these following codes to delete older posts and newer posts links in `functions.php` but it still shows them.

```
 function remove_post_navigation() {
    remove_action('thematic_navigation_below', 'thematic_nav_below', 2);
        remove_action('thematic_navigation_above', 'thematic_nav_above', 2);
}
add_action('init', 'remove_post_navigation');
```

How to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding this in a child theme's functions.php file? From what I read, you can use these empty functions to accomplish what you want.

```
function childtheme_override_nav_above() { }
function childtheme_override_nav_below() { }
```

http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/how-to-remove-nav-from-single-post#post-17191

Comment: I add to function.php. Should I add to child theme's function.php? where is that?

Comment: Ok, sounds like you're not using a child theme so the functions I suggested won't do anything for you. I downloaded Thematic and pasted in the same code you used above (into wp-content/themes/thematic/functions.php) and the "older posts" and "newer posts" links were gone. Sure you pasted in the same spot? You should also disable any plugins while testing.

Comment: Any luck with this aliboy38?

Comment: no it didn't work